# Need to understand how look around is used to extract non overlapping sequences

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to find out non-overlapping matches of a substring in an input text. E.g:

> Find occurrences of 'aa' in 'aaadaa'

```
print(re.findall(r'aa', 'aaadaa'))
```

prints `['aa', 'aa']` as expected since it is finding the non - overlapping

Usage of look - around (positive lookahead here)

```
print(re.findall(r'(?=(aa))', 'aaadaa'))
```

prints `['aa', 'aa', 'aa']`

Need inputs to understand how the above works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aaadaa
--
 1
 --
  2
    --
     3
```

When in lookahead , it can backtrack even after successful match, because it does not consume string.It is just an assertion.
Without a lookahead, once the first `aa` is consumed, regex engine will move forward.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the concept.